# JMeter WebDriver Sampler - headless Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, jmeter, headless

Is it possible to run Firefox headless with WebDriver Sampler? I have used the "Use Chrome headless mode" option with Chrome before, but I don't see that option in Firefox Driver Config.

Perhaps this can be done in the actual sampler, by setting options to 'browser' in the code below?

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() 
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org') 
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy/GUI way of doing this using WebDriver Sampler (unless you patch [FirefoxDriverConfig](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/FirefoxDriverConfig.java) to include [FirefoxBinary](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html) and pass to it `--headless` argument like:

```
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");
```

Another option would be switching to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to initialise the FirefoxDriver class yourself from the scratch.

More information: [Firefox - Headless Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode)

And last but not the least, if you're about to execute your Selenium tests on i.e. Linux machine which doesn't have GUI you can create a virtual display using [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) so Firefox would run attached to this virtual desktop. See [Headless Execution of Selenium Tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins) for more details on implementing this on different operating systems.